# Prompt multiple user input fail

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {  
    var inStr string  
    var inStr2 string  
    fmt.Printf("Input? ")  
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &inStr)  
    fmt.Printf("\nOutput: %s\n", inStr)  
    fmt.Printf("Input2? ")  
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &inStr2)  
    fmt.Printf("\nOutput: %s\n", inStr2)  
}
```

this is output

```
Input? 2
Output: 2  
Input2?   
Output:     
Success: process exited with code 0.
```

As you can see, it does not  allow me to enter input2; it exits the program.

Answer (score 2):

These symptoms can occur on Windows, where lines may end with "`\r\n`" instead of "`\n`". Try adding an explicit newline ("`\n`") to the `Scanf` format. For example, `"%s\n"`,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var inStr string
    var inStr2 string
    fmt.Printf("Input? ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &inStr)
    fmt.Printf("\nOutput: %s\n", inStr)
    fmt.Printf("Input2? ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &inStr2)
    fmt.Printf("\nOutput: %s\n", inStr2)
}
```

Output:

```
Input? 1

Output: 1
Input2? 2

Output: 2
```